# App's metadata rejected by Apple: "Cant locate In App Purchase in my App".?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

Today my Apps metadata was rejected from Apple, this is what they say:

> We have begun the review of your app but aren't able to continue
>   because we can't locate the In App Purchase within your app.
>
> At your earliest opportunity, please reply to this message providing
>   the steps for locating the In App Purchase in your app.
>
> While your iTunes Connect Application State is displayed as Rejected,
>   it is not necessary to upload a new binary. Once you reply to this
>   message, we can proceed with your review.

I am not able to understand, how cant they find my In App Purchase, because this is the same App, Apple rejected because I did not include the "Restore" button in my In App Purchase.

Now they say: "Cant find In App Purchase".. ? :O

What exactly could be the problem here ? They have asked me to reply to them, I dont understand what to say to them.

Also, do i have to submit the new MetaData.. ?

Comment: Please directly contact the corresponding contact person on your case on the issue. There is no help for you to post here

Comment: There should not be any new submission then, maybe you need to provide them the flow with screenshot about your in-app purchase function

Comment: I want to understand, what is happening here.. ? Is it because of what Monish?Yeshesh are saying down there or they cannot find the screen where I have kept the purchases ..!

Comment: better do both. re-submit your in-app purchases to Apple and provide some flow with screenshots to keep the mouths of the Apple engineers shut.

Comment: In App Purchase status is "In review", not possible to resubmit it now ? but, will i have to submit new metadata.. ?

Comment: If not possible to re-submit, then just confirm your in-app purchases are successfully submitted to Apple and notify Apple thru email.

Comment: Can i just ask this .. through the resolution center ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have implement InApp purchase then you have submit all in AppPurchase .To find inApp purchase:

**iTunesConnect -> Manage Your Apps -> Select App -> Manage In App purchases.**

if inApp purchase are not submitted then please submit it.

Comment: I have submitted the In App Purchase item, the status of the item says its "In Review"

Comment: Once your InApp purchase submitted then after upload your binary to review so that Apple can test your InApp purchase.

Comment: Thats right ..! That is what i have done, they can not find it within my App.

Comment: Wait till your InApp purchase submitted to the AppStore . After that upload your binary.

Comment: Do i have to submit the MetaData again ?

Comment: Yes you have to submit it again.

Comment: Okay, thanks..!! the status of the App is now again "In Review".

Answer (score 3):

You have not submitted in app purchases. in app purchase must be selected while uploading the binary file.

Comment: I have submitted the my In App Purchase item, since its status says .. "In Review".

Comment: Oh ok just go to itunes page and there is section review. Edit it and tell them step where you have implemented Buy/Purchase button. They are not getting the buy button in app.

Comment: Okay ..I did it. I have mentioned where I have kept the In App Purchase item in the App. 
But, still i really find this strange, since Apple had rejected my App because I did not include the "Restore" feature in the In App Purchase, Now they are saying they cannot find it.. ?

Comment: Yup Apple testing team is not professional I think. Last week they rejected my app. and when I contacted to review appeal then they live it in 3 hours.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with an incompetent reviewer. I am spelling out in great detail in review notes where to cause the in app purchase options to appear. Already been rejected twice now with that same reason. Thanks to this thread hopefully I have a better idea why. It's so weird getting rejected like this when all my in app purchases are already approved.

Comment: @PsychoDad if they are rejecting on same reason then appeal on apple developer from. i hope they will check it.

Comment: Giving them instructions in the review notes did the trick

Comment: Thats Great. I faced same issue many time. then we need to explain every step.